# Stored procedure returns 0 instead of value

Tags: sql, sql-server, rdbms

There is a stored procedure that can return top 1 result as

```
USE [DB]
GO
.....

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GET] 
    (@in VARCHAR(10), @Out VARCHAR(10) OUTPUT)
AS 
    SELECT top 1 @Out = tab.Col  
    FROM table tab


    RETURN
GO
```

When I call it in main query

```
DECLARE @output VARCHAR(10)
DECLARE @in VARCHAR(10)
DECLARE @Out VARCHAR(10)

EXECUTE dbo.GET @in = 'table', @Out = @output
```

It prints `@output` as  0;

but if I do

```
EXECUTE dbo.GET @in = 'table', @Out = @Out
```

And print `@out`, I get the correct value.

Why could this happen?

I did pass output `@Out` to pre-defined variable `@output`

Comment: Please refer https://www.codeproject.com/articles/794765/sql-server-how-to-write-stored-procedures-with-out

Comment: Procedural code is **highly vendor-specific** - so please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely. The code *appears* to be for SQL Server, but `LIMIT 1` is a MySQL construct not available in SQL Server ......

Comment: Please tag the rdbms. If it's for SQL server then note: 1. You never do anything with `@OutPK` or populate `@Out` inside the proc; 2. You also need to use `OUTPUT` when calling a stored proc with an output variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming SQLS due to presence of 'dbo' and sqlserver tag

Your query in the procedure doesn't assign a value to the out parameter (called @out) it assigns to some other variable called @outpk. Resolve the naming mismatch and make them the same

Sqlserver does not support LIMIT. To limit result set size use `SELECT TOP 1 *`. Using TOP (or any similar result set restrictor) without ORDER BY is illogical. Specify an ORDER BY

In sqlserver, output parameters must be passed with the OUTPUT keyword when calling the procedure:

```
EXEC sprocname @inputparameter ='value', @outputparameter = @variableToSet OUTPUT;
```

Use semicolons; omitting them is deprecated

---

Example

```
USE [DB]
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GET] 
    (@in VARCHAR(10), @OutPk VARCHAR(10) OUTPUT)
AS 
    SELECT @OutPK = tab.Col  
    FROM table tab
    ORDER BY tab.Col;
GO

DECLARE @output VARCHAR(10);

EXECUTE dbo.GET @in = 'table', @OutPK = @output OUTPUT

SELECT @output;
```

Comment: Actually it was my typo. I did use @Out = tab.Col  in the SP. Would you please explain why it was still not returning right result?

Comment: I expect it was the missing OUTPUT keyword when executing the proc. You probably managed to arrange a situation where `@out` had a value thanks to being set in the procedure, but @output could only ever get a value from being set in the EXECUTE call, and omitting the OUTPUT keyword meant that didn’t happen. Long story short; remember the output keyword when you pass a parameter to an output argument of a stored procedure

Answer (score 0):

If its MySql (Limit is in mySql), you can simply call:

```
Call dbo.GET('table', @out);
```

No need to have separate variable `@output`.